# Получить в json список файлов из папки на хостинге

Tags: javascript, json

Есть хостинг на jino. Поддержка PHP не куплена и не планируется.

На хостинге есть папка music с подпапками jass, pop, classic и т.д. В каждой такой папке треки.

Можно ли с помощью javascript или еще как-то получить json файл, который будет описывать содержимое папки music примерно в следующем виде:

```
{
    "music": [
        {
            "musictype": "jass",
            "filename": "misuc1.mp3",
            "filesize": "3,5 MB"
        },
        {
            "musictype": "jass",
            "filename": "misuc2.mp3",
            "filesize": "3,1 MB"
        },
        {
            "musictype": "pop",
            "filename": "misuc1.mp4",
            "filesize": "3,5 MB"
        },
        {
            "musictype": "classic",
            "filename": "misuc2.mp4",
            "filesize": "3,1 MB"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Можно. Напишите его руками

Comment: Мне нужно динамически его получить при открытии страницы https://mydomain.myjino.ru/music

Comment: Ну получайте, в чём проблема?

Comment: Я не знаком с JS, в основном писал на java. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch, но файл таки придётся написать руками